# Only assign role to users with 1+ roles in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I created a bot that will add a role to all users in a 6K+ user Discord server, so we can manage trolling easier with only allowing members with a certain role to type in specific channels. Problem is, I want to only give the role to users with 1+ roles already on the server.

Using Discord.js, I have come up with the following code that works perfect to give the role to all users (I have tested on another server), but I want to make it specifically only add to users with 1+ roles already.

Thanks for any help in advance!

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Bot has started, with ${client.users.size} users, in ${client.channels.size} channels of ${client.guilds.size} guilds.`); 
});


client.on("message", async message => {

  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
  
  if(command === "addalltorole") {
   process.setMaxListeners(0);
 let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == 'Community')
 if (!role) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role not found`)

 message.guild.members.filter(m => !m.user.bot).forEach(member => member.addRole(role))
 message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role **${role.name}** was added to all members`)

  }

});

client.login(config.token);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members

You can use this parameter to get all the members in a guild once you have a reference to a Guild. You can then filter it down to just those with more than one role:

```
guild.members.filter(member => member.roles.array().length > 0).forEach(member => member.addRole(role));
```

Something like this is the general premise and should work.

Comment: This is the error I get in terminal
-
`(node:74134) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 guildMemberUpdate listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:74134) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at item.request.gen.end (/Users/redacted/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:79:15)
    at then (/Users/redacted/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)`

Comment: Has that error been occurring since the start or has it just started with this new code.

Comment: Just with the new code, the original code works fine but gives it to ALL members. This error occurs only when I use the line you kindly provided to attempt to limit to people with > 0 roles. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: The error does specify missing permissions: Missing Permissions at item.request.gen.end ; did you try adding them in the discord api console

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out, I was dumb and had the role I was trying to add above the bot role :facepalm: thanks again!

Comment: Accept answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Bot has started, with ${client.users.size} users, in ${client.channels.size} channels of ${client.guilds.size} guilds.`); 
});


client.on("message", async message => {

  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;
 
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
  
  if(command === "addalltorole") {
     process.setMaxListeners(0);
     let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == 'BIGROLE')
    if (!role) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role not found`)
      message.guild.members.filter(member => member.roles.array().length > 1).forEach(member => member.addRole(role));

/* message.guild.members.filter(m => !m.user.bot).forEach(member => member.addRole(role))
*/  
    message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role **${role.name}** was added to all members`)

  }

});

client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Am I missing something simple here?